# why does input cursor go to the start in textfield? flutter

Tags: flutter

```
TextField(
                                controller: tecTitle,
                                onChanged: (String title) {
                                  this.title = title;
                                  offset: this.title.length;
                                },

                                maxLines: 1,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  hintText: 'Title',
                                ),
                              ),
```

```
var tecTitle = TextEditingController(
            text: title,
          );
```

[cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX2iE.gif)

since I clicked the textfield to edit it, the cursor goes to the start. how can I fix it? Ive tried set the selection in TextEditingController, but selection isnt defined in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below code, your controller should be initialized as a below

```
 _editingController = new TextEditingController.fromValue(
            new TextEditingValue(
                text: title,
                selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(
                    offset: title.length)));
```

Comment: now it works perfectly as I expected. many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using selection of TextEditingController and 'fromPosition' method of TextSelction, you can control position of input.

```
var tecTitle = TextEditingController(
            text: title,
          );
tecTitle.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: title.length));
setState(() {});
```

Comment: Could you call 'setState((){})' after end of phase?

Comment: I cant call it, it throws an error. maybe its because the textfield is in futurebuilder.